# next multiple of a number to given multiplier

Tags: java, algorithm, function, math, double

I want to write a function to find the next multiple of a number given a multiplier. Both the source number and multiplier could be floating point.

expected:

```
nextMult(3.654,0.5) = 4.0
nextMult(3.165,0.15) = 3.30
nextMult(3.452,0.002) = 3.452
nextMult(2, 0.3) = 2.1
nextMult(2, 0.2) = 2
nextMult(4, 3) = 6
```

My current solution:

```
public double nextMult(double source, double multiplier)
{
    for (double i = (double)((long)source - multiplier); i <= source + multiplier; 
        i += multiplier) 
    {
        if (i >= source) 
            return i;
    }
}
```

I don't like the multiple castings. Are there more efficient ways or existing library solutions that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

both source and multiplier are of type: double

```
double result = Math.ceil(source/multiplier) * multiplier;
```

This works for all your test cases...

Comment: Yeah, this works. Just need to change the second `source` to multiplier.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is. Since you've provided a working solution, you will notice that you've presented an O(n) solution that goes through a set number of operations and appears to increment until you've found it. This becomes terrifying when you do `nextMult(10000000000000, 1);` We'd be here all day iterating through that loop by hand.

However, there is actually an O(1) solution.

```
int multiple = (int) (source / multiplier); //we get the whole number portion of the divided value, i.e. 4/3 = 1, 3.654/0.5 = 7
double remainder = source % multiplier; //we need to check for if it matches the higher
if(remainder > 0) {
    multiple++; // and we want the next higher one
}
return multiplier * multiple;
```

That being said, **this only handles POSITIVE values.** *I will leave handling the negative values up to you as an exercise.*

*Edit:* You will need to implement BigDoubles for modulus. Doubles and modulus apparently hate each other.

Comment: nextMult(10000000000000, 1); will iterate only once by my solution. also this solution doesnt work for my test case nextMult(4, 3) = 6

Comment: @Rohit I just tested on my box and 4,3 works. There's a problem with using modulus with doubles, but using `BigDecimal` instead of `double` should address issues.

Comment: tried your edited answer... nextMult(3.452,0.002) gives 3.454 for some reason... thanks.